# Dealing with recursive method

Tags: java, recursion, methods, numeric

so i have a diamond over here. i have to do it now in recursive way. i am only a beginner and asking you for help. Recursive method is kinda hard for me.

```
    1
   222
  33333
 4444444
555555555
 4444444
  33333
   222
    1
```

the code i used: without recursion:

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
    drawNumDiamond(9);

}
public static void drawNumDiamond(int h) {
    int noofColumns= 1;
    int noofSpaces = 4;
    int start=0;
    for (int i = 1; i <= h; i++) {
        if (i<5) {
            start=i;
        } else {
            start=10-i;
        }

        for (int j = 1; j <= noofSpaces; j++) {
            System.out.print(" ");

        }
        for (int j = 1; j <= noofColumns; j++) {
            System.out.print(start);

        }
        System.out.println();
        if (i < 5) {
            noofColumns = noofColumns+2;
            noofSpaces = noofSpaces-1;
        } else {
            noofColumns = noofColumns-2;
            noofSpaces = noofSpaces + 1;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `"Recursive method is kinda hard for me."` -- and it will likely remain that way if you don't at least try. Come on now, it's not asking too much to see you show at least some attempt, is it? Plus it's part of the rules of this site, that all homework related questions should show a good faith attempt.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels agreed. Start with a trivial diamond (size 1), then try size 3 by making that method call itself.  Size 1 will be your base case, size 3 bits will be the start of your recursive case.

Answer (score 1):

I will simplify the iterative way of printing the diamonds so that it can be easily extended to recursive function. 
 **Iterative:**

```
public static void diamond(int n){

    boolean increase = true;
    int val = 1;
    while(val > 0){
        spaces(n-val);
        printValue(2*val-1,val);
        if(val >= n) increase = false;
        if(increase) val++;
        else val--;
    }
}

private static void printValue(int times, int val) {
    for (int i = 0; i < times; i++) {
        System.out.print(val);
    }
    System.out.println();

}

private static void spaces(int times) {
    for (int i = 0; i < times; i++) {
        System.out.print(" ");
    }

}
```

Try to call the diamond method inside itself and remove the while loop. Add  additional parameters to it so as to determine when to end the recursion and when to decrease the value to be printed.